# Stuck at ElasticSearch GroupBy query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have this SQL query and EVENT table in my Oracle database.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
CITY,
max(DATE) AS eventdate
FROM EVENT
WHERE TYPE = 'CRASH'
GROUP BY CITY
ORDER BY eventdate DESC, CITY ASC)
WHERE ROWNUM < 6;

NEW YORK 15/02/27
LONDON 15/02/27
LONDON 15/02/27
LONDON 15/02/11
LONDON 15/02/19

EVENT: ID, NAME, DATE, CITY, TYPE
```

I want to do the same query in ElasticSearch using JavaAPI.
Is it possible? I am a beginner, don't know how to start. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) doesnt have any examples for my case or I'cant see them.

I must know 6 cities that have the latest events and their dates. 
Then I will ask ElasticSearch for 3 last events for these cities. I think I must do two queries as it is not possible to have result like this in one response: CITY->listOf3LastEvents, CITY2->listOf3LastEvents, City3->listOf3LastEvents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's say your event documents are simply modeled like this:

```
{
   "id": 123,
   "name": "Some event name",
   "event_date": "2016-09-02T12:00:00.000Z",
   "city": "New York",
   "type": "CRASH"
}
```

Now let's create an index with a reasonable mapping for the above document:

```
PUT events
{
  "mappings": {
    "event": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "event_date": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can now index the above document (+ a few others) with the following command:

```
PUT events/event/123
{
   "id": 123,
   "name": "Some event name",
   "event_date": "2016-09-02T12:00:00.000Z",
   "city": "New York",
   "type": "CRASH"
}
```

Finally, you'll be able to send a query that is equivalent to your SQL query like this:

```
POST events/event/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "type": "CRASH"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "city.raw",
        "size": 6,
        "order": {
          "latest": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest": {
          "max": {
            "field": "event_date"
          }
        },
        "last_3_events": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 3,
            "sort": {
              "event_date": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I did something similar already, didn't see the response :) Still I have a question abaout top_hits and buckets. In bucket I can have document count = 100 for example but only 3 documents in tophit aggregation hits. What guarantees me that among 100 documents in the bucket those 3 chosen by TopHit aggregation are correct - sorted by date ?

Comment: Yes, the sort by date will guarantee you that